# How to display an entry from an array in a prepareforSegue according to a value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode

I have one array that has objects, and these objects are displayed in a `TableViewController` and each row has some fields, like `team id`, `name` and `points`.

Now I created an `additional team info` array with more objects/properties as - full team name, foundation year and **team id** again etc.

What I want is that, when the user clicks in a row in my `TableViewController` it reads the team id and in the `prepareforSegue` has some way of searching my `additional team info` array and find the matching team id and display that object data in another segue. Below is some of my code:

```
NSMutableArray *allInfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {

    ExtraTeamInfoObject *temp = [[ExtraTeamInfoObject alloc] init];

    temp.teamFullNames = _teamFullNames[i];
    temp.teamId = _teamId[i];
    temp.teamStadiumNames = _teamStadiumNames[i];
    temp.stadiumCapacity = _stadiumCapacity[i];
    temp.clubFoundationDate = _clubFoundationDate[i];
    temp.stadiumBuiltYear = _stadiumBuiltYear[i];
    temp.teamCity = _teamCity[i];
    temp.clubPresident = _clubPresident[i];
    temp.headCoach = _headCoach[i];
    temp.championshipsWon = _championshipsWon[i];
    temp.domesticCupsWon = _domesticCupsWon[i];
    temp.domesticLeagueCupsWon = _domesticLeagueCupsWon[i];
    temp.domesticSuperCupsWon = _domesticSuperCupsWon[i];
    temp.championsleaguesWon = _championshipsWon[i];
    temp.europaleaguesWon = _europaleaguesWon[i];
    temp.europeanSuperCupsWon = _europeanSuperCupsWon[i];
    temp.worldclubchampionshipsWon = _worldclubchampionshipsWon[i];

    [allInfo addObject:temp];
}

for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    NSLog(@"Show me the goods %@", [allInfo[i] teamFullNames]); // just making sure the objects are being created correctly.
    }
}


-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"teamDetailsSeg"]){

        TeamDetailsTableViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        long row = [myIndexPath row];

        //detailViewController.teamDetailModel = before I would just type the array here like _teamFullName[row] and it would give me data i needed

    }
}
```

Comment: For seraching purposes you may user a dictionary instead of an array with structure: @(team_id) => ExtraTeamInfoObject

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"teamDetailsSeg"] && [segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[TeamDetailsTableViewController Class]){

        TeamDetailsTableViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        long row = [myIndexPath row];


        //detailViewController.teamDetailModel =  before i would just type the array here like _teamFullName[row] and it would give me data i needed

        NSNumber *teamID = _teamFullName[row];

        for (ExtraTeamInfoObject *item in allInfo) {
            if ([item.teamID integerValue] == [teamID integerValue]) {
                detailViewController.extraInfo = allInfo[allInfo indexOfObject:item];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I agree with vokilam. NSDictionary is much better choice for you.

**Edit**

Something like:

```
self.teamArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // assume you have @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *teamArray;

NSString *teamID = @"123456";
NSString *name = @"Chelsea";
NSNumber *points = @56; // or whatever your objects are

NSDictionary *extraTeamInfo = @{@"teamFullName" : @"Chelsea F.C.",
                                @"teamStadiumName" : @"Stamford Bridge",
                                @"stadiumCapacity" : @41837,
                                @"clubFoundationDate" : @1905}; // etc. fill all fields

// repeat this for each team and add each dictionary into the array however you obtain the data
// you may think a better array/dictionary structure for easier updates based on your use case

[self.teamArray addObject:@[teamID, name, points, extraTeamInfo]];
```

And then your cellForRowAtIndexPath might look like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.nameLabel.text    cell.nameLabel.text = [self.teamArray[indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:1];
    NSUInteger points = [[[self.teamArray[indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:2]; integerValue];
    cell.pointsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", points];

    return cell;
}
```

And prepareForSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"teamDetailsSeg"]) {

        TeamDetailsTableViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        detailViewController.extraTeamInfo = [self.teamArray[indexPath.row] lastObject];
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it seems to not be working, when i click in a row it takes me to the other segue, but the segue labels are empty: http://pastebin.com/qf5njjc7

Comment: Well, I don't have your full code, so the solution was just a hint in which direction you should go. I have no idea of the teamID type etc. If you provide full code related to this master class and the detail even with some dummy data in arrays, I can review it. You should really check NSDictionary. See my edit for how you can approach it.